# Titanium Android videoPlayer loads, has endPlaybackTime, just won't play

Tags: android, video, titanium

I'm trying to play a video on Android and having some weird issues, I've stripped my code right back to the following to try and separate it from any view issues elsewhere in my app...
the file does seems to be loading, the following comments are the console log which shows it has the video file size and playable duration. However, the playback controls show 0 length, and just a black screen. The video is an mp4, it plays fine, I can only assume the emulator/devices I've tried this on support the format and it's not corrupt, as they are able to read it's duration... what else could stop it playing?!

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('file:///data/data/com.app.applite/app_appdata/master/D9E3BC7A_225C_458B_B298_C4.mp4');
console.log('Size: '+file.size); // Size: 269245

var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    url : file.nativePath,
    backgroundColor : 'blue',
    movieControlMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_FULLSCREEN,
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
    fullscreen : true,
    autoplay : true
});

activeMovie.addEventListener('loadstate', function(evt) {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(evt));
    // "playableDuration":8315 Correct duration!!!
    // {"type":"loadstate","source":{"autoplay":true,"currentPlaybackTime":0,"bubbleParent":true,"playableDuration":8315,"rect":{"height":854,"y":0,"x":0,"width":480},"keepSc    reenOn":false,"url":"file:///data/data/com.app.applite/app_appdata/master/D9E3BC7A_225C_458B_B298_C4.mp4","size":{"height":854,"y":0,"width":480,"x":0},"volume":1,"    endPlaybackTime":8315,"backgroundColor":"blue","playing":true,"playbackState":1,"mediaControlStyle":2,"duration":8315,"movieControlMode":2,"scalingMode":2,"initialPlaybac    kTime":0,"loadState":1,"backgroundRepeat":false,"movieControlStyle":2,"children":[],"fullscreen":true,"_events":{"loadstate":{}}},"currentPlaybackTime":0,"loadState":0,"b    ubbles":true,"cancelBubble":false}
    activeMovie.play();
});
// Tried with and without these, makes no difference
activeMovie.show();
activeMovie.play();
```

Comment: Can you test if it works when you place your video within the resources folder? Let's say url: '/video/D9E3BC7A_225C_458B_B298_C4.mp4'.   


Better, can you test if it works saving [the example video from the kitchensink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/etc/movie.mp4) to the same path?

Comment: Actually the sample movie does seem to work fine in Resources, but this video still doesn't. I guess this file is somehow subtly corrupt or incompatible, yet it plays fine in everything else and the video player even knows how long it is! Also, I've had videos from the same source and same encoding settings working on Android before, weird! Thanks for your advice, I think I'll start trying different videos and see if I can narrow the problem down :(